# Функция cin.get()

Tags: c++

Объясните пожалуйста мне функцию `cin.get()`. Прочитал про него в Дейтел, но там как то не очень подробно и хорошо она описана. Может кто-то мне поподробнее рассказать, если не трудно?

Comment: А что, кроме Дейтолов других учебников и справочников не существует? И выход в интернет тоже перекрыли?

Answer (score 7):

Когда метод `get()` вызывается с аргументом типа char или вообще аргументов, он извлекает следующий символ ввода, даже если это пробел, знак табуляции или символ новой строки. Версия `get(char& ch)` присваивает входящий символ своему аргументу, а версия `get(void)` просто использует входной символ, преобразует его в целочисленный тип (обычно - int) и возвращает это значение.

Плюс пару слов об еще парочке перегруженных разновидностях:

```
istream &get (char *buf, streamsize num);
istream &get (char *buf, streamsize num, char delim);
```

Первая форма функции `get()` считывает символы в массив, на который ссылается указатель `buf`, пока не будет считан num - 1 символов, обнаружен символ перехода на следующую строку или достигнут конец файла. Эта функция записывает нулевой символ в конец массива, на который ссылается указатель `buf`. Символ перехода на новую строку **не считывается** (!). Он остается в потоке, пока не будет выполнена следующая операция ввода.

Вторая форма функции `get ()` считывает символы в массив, на который ссылается указатель `buf`, пока не будет считан `num - 1` символов, обнаружен символ *delim* или достигнут конец файла. Функция записывает нулевой символ в конец массива, на который ссылается указатель `buf`. Символ *delim* **не считывается** (!). Он остается в потоке, пока не будет выполнена следующая операция ввода.

Comment: Неплохо было бы в своем ответе поподробнее остановиться на возвращаемом значении для разновидностей. Когда и для чего его нужно использовать.

Answer (score 2):

`int istream::get();`

Извлекает символ из потока и возвращает его значение (приведенное к целому).

Если возникает ошибка, то в потоке (например, `cin`) устанавливаются флаги:

`eofbit` - попытка чтения, когда достигнут конец потока.

`failbit` - символы не были извлечены, потому что либо достигнут конец потока, либо операция вставки в пункт назначения не удалась (это относится только к `streambuf`).

`badbit` - в случае других ошибок.

Для проверки этих флагов можно использовать функцию `good()`.

[Документация](http://cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/get/) на сайте cplusplus.com.
[Справка на русском языке](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/ru/io/get) на сайте cppreference.com

---

Также потоки приводятся к типу `bool`, что позволяет писать такой код:

```
istream in;
...
string s;
while (in >> s) // оператор >> вернет ссылку на поток, который преобразуется в bool
{
    cout << s << ' ';
}
```

Comment: Видимо следует заметить, что **get это перегруженный** (? overload не знаю правильный ли термин ?) метод. При вызове с разными аргументами (их тип и количество) ведет себя по разному, хотя суть остается - ввод символов из потока. 

IMHO именно в этом затруднения у @navi1893.

Comment: да! именно в этом! Но спасибо вам за ответы!

Answer (score -2):

Команда cin.get() - это еще один вызов функции, которая считывает данные из входного потока данных и ожидает нажатия клавиши ENTER.